# Cannot connect remote desktop to server due to "CredSSP encryption" issue after updates (Windows 10 Home)

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-connection

Recently, I made an update to my laptop and it stopped connecting to a server via RDP, showing the below message.

```
[Window Title]
Remote Desktop Connection

[Content]
An authentication error has occurred.
The function requested is not supported

Remote computer: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
This could be due to CredSSP encryption oracle remediation.
For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866660

[OK]
```

After some internet searches, I came across this article - https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2018/05/windows-10-rdp-credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation-error-fix/.  This explains that the issue is because of latest updates not allowing access to unpatched servers, and explaining how to change your settings to allow connecting even to unpatched servers. In an ideal world, the server would be patched and this would not be an issue. However, that might not happen for a while and I need to find a workaround.

The first issue seems that Windows 10 Home does not have the `Group Policy Editor` installed.  I managed to find an article showing how to get the `gpedit.msc` back.

However, then I couldn't find the entry `Computer Configuration >> Administrative Templates >> System >> Credentials Delegation >> Encryption Oracle Remediation.` explained in the article about the update. Again, I am assuming this is because I am using Windows Home 10.

Any ideas how to fix this issue on Windows 10 Home?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote desktop connection error after updating Windows 2018/05/08 - CredSSP updates for CVE-2018-0886](https://superuser.com/questions/1321418/remote-desktop-connection-error-after-updating-windows-2018-05-08-credssp-upda)

Comment: @Run5k I actually referenced an article in my question to show that I am aware similar issues exist. The difference in my question is that I am using Windows 10 Home, and the fix mentioned does not seem to apply.

Comment: Understood, but there are actually several fixes listed within that question.  The one with that [adds registry keys](https://superuser.com/a/1321423/650163) seems like it should work on Windows 10 Home, also.

Answer (score 6):

- regedit → `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\`
- Create a key named `CredSSP`
- In `CredSSP`, create a key named `Parameters`
- In `Parameters`, create a `DWORD (32) Value` named `AllowEncryptionOracle`
- Double click `AllowEncryptionOracle` and change its value to `00000002`

You don't have to reboot.